# Call global variable before it is set using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Okay, this has me confused once again. I am trying to either A: set a golbal variable, which i can do or B: retieve a variable from my `AsyncTask`. I have set can set the golbal variable from asynctask which is fine, but the activity calls it before it is set with the asynctask.

So therefore I need the application to finsh the AsyncTask before calling the golbal variable.

```
new createUser().execute();                         
Log.i("res", "After: " + Boolean.toString(MyProperties.getInstance().valut));

private class createUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Creating User...", true);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (db.createUser(nameU.getText().toString(), userU.getText()
                .toString(), emailU.getText().toString(), passU.getText()
                .toString()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (!result) {
            toast.setText("User already exists!");
            toast.show();
            res = result;
            MyProperties.getInstance().valut = res;
            Log.i("res", Boolean.toString(MyProperties.getInstance().valut));

        } else {
            toast.setText("Success");
            toast.show();
            res = result;
            MyProperties.getInstance().valut = res;
            Log.i("res", Boolean.toString(MyProperties.getInstance().valut));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with your global variable in `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`. You need to implement it in your `AsyncTask`'s child. This method is called then all work is done.

**EDIT**

```
private class createUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (db.createUser(nameU.getText().toString(), userU.getText()
                .toString(), emailU.getText().toString(), passU.getText()
                .toString()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Creating User...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            result?"Success":"User already exists!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyProperties.getInstance().valut = result
        Log.i("res", Boolean.toString(MyProperties.getInstance().valut));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, and what is the problem? AsyncTask.execute() is returning immediately. You can't rely on result of a task just after the call, you need to put all your logic in onPostExecute method.

Comment: what happens is that when i call the variable in the Log.i it displays the initial value 'false' not the value that is assigned with the onPostExecute runs. when i look at the DDMS the Log.i "after" runs before the Log.i in the onPostExecute, i need it to be the other way around.

Comment: Yes, and it is right! You need to understand what the AsyncTask is and what it for. It is for running some task asynchronously. And get a result asynchronously also. I'll try to explain you how the code flows... Firstly you are starting an AsyncTask via execute() call. Then, just right after the call, in the same nanosecond your Log.i("after") occuring. An AsyncTask is start running now in another thread. And then it is complete the onPostExecute method is invoked. It can be invoked just a second later, or a hour later.

Comment: ok, so i guess i want to return a the variable from the AysncTask when finish. would this be possible?

Comment: No, you need not. You shuld do all your processing related to asynchronous task result just in `onPostExecute` method and not in any other place.

Comment: well the problem then is when i try to dismiss the dialog box. the dialog.show is call before the Asynctask and then needs to be dismissed after the asynctask has confirmed that it was a success but stays open to edit the fields. i was using this golbal variable to check to see if it was a success or not.

Comment: i tried to dismiss the dialog inside asynctask but it is un resolved. i also tried setting up the dialog before the main activity but the application forcecloses

Comment: I've edited my answer. Lokke there, this is how i think your AsyncTask must look like. You need to create and show your ProgressDialog in `onPreExecute` and in `onPostExecute` dismiss it.

Comment: ok got that part, now i have another dialog box that is before the asynctask, when the New User button is clicked. I need this to be dismiss when the task is complete and a success, otherwise it needs to stay visible so that user can edit this.

Comment: Well, dismiss it in onPostExecute method depending on result value.

Comment: it wont let me, the dialog is out of the scope and when i put in the scope of the class it force closes

Comment: Show me your code. How an where are you creating a dialog? And where are async task is started

Comment: Got it, i just created a boolean var using .get() on the task and check if the result was true or not. thanks for you help. 

i just thought of that, i was up most of the night thinking about it. still learning threads. sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- Java does not really have any global variables.  The closest it has are static class variables.  Since you haven't shown your declared variable, I can't say what you've really implemented.
- Every AsyncTask has a onPostExecute(..) method you can override that runs in the original thread/Looper after doInBackground(..) has completed.  Override this to do things like Update the UI thread.